# IAR for ARM kickstart edition 32K code limit

Tags: compiler-construction, iar

Free, but code size limited to 32K.
The question being, if I declare an array, eg char array[33000] does that count as code or data given that the ARM Cortex M4 that I am using is a Harvard architecture?

Answer (score 1):

In IAR your variables will end up in `rwdata` or `rodata` sections (if declared `const`). I believe the limit specifically applies to code (via `rocode` or `rwcode` sections). Here's an example output from a .map file for a project I have:

```
  214 749 bytes of readonly  code memory
   28 705 bytes of readonly  data memory
   97 220 bytes of readwrite data memory
```

The readonly data are `const` items, readwrite data are all the variables, and readonly code is all my code. Some immediate data values may end up in `rocode`, but I would consider it unlikely that this would take an significant portion of the 32kB code limit.

I would consider another toolchain if you believe that you may bump against the 32kB limit.